# static variable followed by extern in the same file

Tags: c++, static, extern

The following piece of code compiles as well as executes fine.
What exactly does the `extern int a` statement mean after `static int a`.
Note that If i write `static int a` after `extern int a`, the compiler throws error as `tests.cpp:6: error: a was declared extern and later static`

```
#include<iostream>
//#include "testh.h"
using namespace std;

static int a;
extern int a;
int main()
{
        int a;
        a=3;
        cout<<a<<endl;
        cout<<::a<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `extern` doesn't cause the compiler to define a variable but declares the existing "somewhere" it. If a variable is already defined as `static` the declaration is ignored. BTW: your main function has another variable `a` that hides all file scope variables with the name `a`.

Comment: I'm referring to static int a inside main as `::a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a variable `static` then `extern`, but not `extern` then `static`.  The result is that the global `a` still has internal linkage.  There is a very similar example (using `b` as the variable name) in the language standard doc, section `[dcl.stc]`, that states this.